# Natural quotient map

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, quotient-spaces, closed-map

Let  $X$ be a Banach space and let  $M $  be a closed subspace of  $X $.

> When is the quotient map $Q :X \to X/M $ closed?

I got somewhere that it happens iff$ M=X$ or $M=(0) $. But I couldn't prove it. Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $M$ a closed subspace such that $\{0\} \ne M \ne X$.
Then there is $x_1\not\in M$ and $x_2\in M\setminus \{0\}$.

Define the closed set 
$$
S:=\{ s x_1 + s^{-1}x_2, \ s>0\}.
$$
Then $Q(S)$ is the following set of equivalence classes
$$
Q(S)= \{ [sx_1]:  \ s>0\}.
$$
This is not closed in $X/M$ as $[sx_1]\to0$ for $s\to0$:
$$
\|[sx_1]\|_{X/M} = \inf_{x\in [sx_1]}\|x\|_X \le s \|x_1\|_X,
$$ but $0\not\in Q(S)$.

This shows that the quotient mapping maps closed sets to closed sets if and only if $M=\{0\}$ or $M=X$.

Comment: Nice argument. Is it some standard technique or did you think of it? If the former, then kindly direct me to a source :)

Comment: It is just an extension of the fact that the projection of the closed set $\{(x,1/x)  \ x>0\}$ in $\mathbb R^2$ onto the $x_1$-axis is not closed.

Comment: Ah, clever. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by "closed map" that the graph of $Q$ is closed, then $Q$ is closed, since $Q$ is bounded:

$||Qx|| \le ||x||$ for all $x \in X$

Comment: By closed map I mean which takes closed sets to closed sets.